# On page or at page

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, usage, grammaticality-in-context, word-in-context

> Open your book at page 80.

> Turn at page 80.

> Open your book to page 80.

> Turn to page 80.

Which preposition is better. Can we use both prepositions with the same meaning, or there is difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual meaning of "to" and "at".  The preposition "to" indicates some kind of motion toward.

So "Open at" or "Open to" are both possible.

But "Turn" suggests motion, so "Turn to".